# How to find outliers variables in a very large dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, data-cleaning, outliers

I want to find the outlier variable in a dataset both in terms of length and value.
In other words, I want to find a variable that is unlike other variables by comparing between variables.

To illustrate, below is a dummy set:

```
outliers <- data.frame(A = c(32, 31, 32, 38, 23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       B = c(33, 39, 28, 34, 32, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       C = c(28, 39, 41, 31, 29, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       D = c(8, 9, 19, 28, 31, 23, 18, 13, 93, 2))
```

Clearly, the variable `D` is the outlier both in terms of **length** of observations and its **values** (i.e. mean).

I want to find a way to locate outlier variables like `D` in my actual dataset and put them into a list for further inspection. 
The difficulty that I have in doing this with my actual dataset is that its very large (there are many lists that contain dataframes with hundreds of columns and thousands of rows).

Thank you!

Comment: It is unclear what you have attempted thus far.

Comment: You may want to explore one of the many exploratory data analysis (EDA) packages in R and pick the one that best meets your needs.  Note that for may of us "outliers variables" is very strange terminology that gets in the way of understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You guys are right. I'll repost this question and make it more clear. Thanks!